# SQL Server: How to return one records from each group

Tags: t-sql

I am facing a problem. so here i am giving my code. please have a look the sample data & select query which is not giving expected result.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Ticker] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ClientCode] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Earnings] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [PrePost] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [LastCSMDeliveredDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Insert into Test(Ticker,ClientCode,Earnings,PrePost,LastCSMDeliveredDate)
values('ABB','ABB','3Q2021','Pre',GetDate()-5),
('ABB','ADS','2Q2021','Pre',GetDate()-10),
('ABB','ABB','2Q2021','Pre',GetDate()-12),

('ANTM','IVZ','3Q2021','Pre',GetDate()-5),
('ANTM','IVZ','2Q2021','Pre',GetDate()-11),
('ANTM','IVZ','3Q2021','Pre',GetDate()-15),

('CSGP','IVZ','3Q2021','Pre',GetDate()-5),
('CSGP','DG','2Q2021','Pre',GetDate()-12),
('CSGP','IVZ','3Q2021','Pre',GetDate()-20)

Select * from test
select top 1 Ticker,ClientCode,Max(Earnings) Earnings,Max(PrePost) AS 
PrePost,Max(LastCSMDeliveredDate) as LastCSMDeliveredDate from test
Group BY Ticker,ClientCode
Order BY Ticker,LastCSMDeliveredDate DESC
```

the above select return only single records but i have **grouped on Ticker,ClientCode**
some time ticker is same but client code is different so multiple records i suppose to come.

definitely i made some mistake in query for which i am not getting right output. so please some one help me to rectify the code.

Thanks

Comment: Try your query which starts with "select top 1" without "top 1".

Comment: @ekochergin i tried without select 1 but getting single records.

Comment: I hate to say it, but @ekochergin was quite clear, Babu. You say that the query only returns a single row, but that's because that *exactly* what you asked for. YOui have `SELECT TOP 1`. If you don't want the "top 1" row, you shouldn't have as `TOP` clause.

Comment: *"i tried without select 1 but getting single records."* I can't replicate your problem.[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9f10fc88bec089c5badaf2fbab1b0779)

Comment: Why did you add the `TOP (1)` clause if you don't want to limit the result set to 1 row, @BabuGoel ? Do you know what `TOP` does?

Comment: @BabuGoel can you perhaps update the question with result you're expecting to see?

Comment: who has given a negative mark to my post. please mention solid reason.

Answer (score -1):

Issue resolved.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ticker,ClientCode ORDER BY LastCSMDeliveredDate DESC) AS rn
   FROM test
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group

Comment: why giving negative mark because this is another way to get desired result.